# I Cannot Run My Discord Bot Code Using Discord Library

Tags: python, discord

```
        import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    # Send a message to the welcome channel
    welcome_channel = member.guild.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
    await welcome_channel.send(f"Welcome {member.mention} to the server!")

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Whenever I Try Running This Code Replacing The Token And The Channel ID It Shows Me A Error Like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    client = discord.Client()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'
 
KeyboardInterrupt

```

Comment: BTW: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=missing+1+required+keyword-only+argument%3A+%27intents%27. Please do a little bit of research up front!

Answer (score 0):

As per the [quickstart](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html) documentation (and the error message), you need to specify the intents you want to use.

Here's an example using the default intents.

```py
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    # Send a message to the welcome channel
    welcome_channel = member.guild.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
    await welcome_channel.send(f"Welcome {member.mention} to the server!")

client.run(TOKEN)
```